# Program in c array

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

[text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)I have to make one array which is A[n][n]. In this array the user puts some numbers and from this array I have to make a second array which is C[n] which numbers are positive number by row from first one. I try do it by this way but in that way it works for every numbers it have to be only by rows .have to look something like that for example
A00:1 A01:-3 A02:5
A10:-7 A11:-8 A12:7
A20:6 A21:9 A22:10

C00:2 C01:1 C02:3
But in my way it look :
C00:3 C01:3 C02:3 which is wrong.
If somebody have an idea where is the problem I will be so thankful.

```
> const int n=10;
    int a[n][n];
    int c[n];
    int i,j,k,suma;
printf("vuvedete br redove i stalbove n=");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        do{
            printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
        
        while(a[i][j]<-1000||a[i][j]>1000);
        }
    }
    suma=0;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            if (a[i][j]>0){
            suma=suma+1;}
        }
    }
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
            printf("c[%d]=%d",k,suma);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to put `suma=0;` inside the `i` loop, before the `j` loop, and use its value after the `j` loop terminates. Currently, you are printing the same grand total `n` times.

Comment: Sorry after I put the sum=0 after the I what I have to move

Comment: To delete the secondly forsook what

Comment: `for (i=0;i<n;i++){` `suma=0;` `for (j=0;j<n;j++){` ... `} /* end of j loop */` `c[i] = suma;` `} /* end of i loop */`.

Comment: for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  suma=0;
  for (j=0;j<n;j++){
  do{
   printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
   scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
  }
  
  while(a[i][j]<-1000||a[i][j]>1000);
  }
  if (a[i][j]>0){
   suma=suma+1;
 }
 }
 
 for(k=0;k<n;k++){
   printf("c[%d]=%d",k,suma);
  }
 return 0;
}

Comment: But in that way it again does not work

Comment: `printf("c[%d]=%d",k,c[k]);`. And I was referring to the loops that include `suma=suma+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

Main changes:

1. Populate array `c[]` and discard variable `suma`. This was the primary issue with your code.
2. You declare `n` as a `const` but then allow user to enter its value. I've removed the const and used a #define to set the max dimensions for the arrays.
3. Removed while loop - what's this for?
4. General tidying up.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10

int main() {
    int a[MAX][MAX] = {0};
    int c[MAX] = {0};
    int n = MAX;
    printf("vuvedete br redove i stalbove n=");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++) 
            c[i] += a[i][j] > 0 ? 1 : 0;

    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        printf("c[%d]=%d\n",k,c[k]);

    return 0;
}
```